# Routes in Codeigniter - 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

Can someone tell me, where the issue is ??

This is my controller

```
class Support extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('support_model');
        $urlarray = array("index","delete");
        if(!in_array($this->uri->segment(2),$urlarray)){
            $this->viewticket($this->uri->segment(2));
        }
    }

    public function viewticket($id){
        if(!empty($id)){
            $this->load->view('templates/logged_header');       
            $this->load->view('support/view');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['benefits'] = 'welcome/benefits';
$route['faqs'] = 'welcome/faqs';
$route['distributors'] = 'welcome/distributors';
$route['contact'] = 'welcome/contact';
$route['purchase'] = 'welcome/purchase';

//login routes
$route['login'] = 'login/index';
$route['logout'] = 'login/logout';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

`localhost/ciproj/support/hello-world` gives me `404 Page Not Found` error

If I use `exit;` after `$this->load->view('templates/footer');`, the page is showing me blank page.

I don't have anything in routes related to support and every other method is working
Is there anything that i'm missing in routes ??

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is `hello-world` pointing to? did you declare a `route` for this? show us the `application/config/routes.php` content.

Comment: hello-world will automatically point to support construct isnt ??
 $this->viewticket($this->uri->segment(2));

Comment: This is really weird then, other than index and delete, I can echo in viewticket()

Comment: can you tell me, how to handle this route please ??
except add, delete every thing should go to viewticket() ??

Comment: if(!in_array($this->uri->segment(2),$urlarray))...if hello-world is not in the $urlarray, then call viewticket(), which is right

Comment: Sorry my bad. That's weird. do you use any route in your `routes.php` config file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging the title, first of all check if your server is running PHP using `CGI/FastCGI` or not (you could simply check that by [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)).

If so, change the following in `config.php`:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

---

Back to the topic, you could achieve that by using the single-line route below within your `routes.php` file:

```
$route['support/(?!index)(?!delete)(:any)'] = "support/viewticket/$1";
```

And remove these lines from your `__construct` method:

```
$urlarray = array("index","delete");
if(!in_array($this->uri->segment(2),$urlarray)){
    $this->viewticket($this->uri->segment(2));
}
```

Let me know how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Since the above answer did not work for me, I just added this function in my default_controller, and it worked.

```
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    }
```

Comment: No, this is not the right solution. We might as well autoload `url` helper

Comment: I didn't say this is the right solution for everyone. In my case, this solved. This might work for someone.